# How to use a range table with LOOP

Tags: abap

I know how to use range tables with SELECTs.
However, is it possible to use it in a LOOP's WHERE condition?
If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: It is the same syntax: LOOP AT ... WHERE field IN range... or do I miss something?

Comment: I wonder how one could improve the ABAP documentation so that people can find the answers themselves ([here](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenlogexp_comp.htm))

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai, I knew it does not work with READ TABLE, I knew it worked with SELECT, and the documentation only talked about SELECTs

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai, mind making this an answer?

Comment: @SandraRossi Agree. The documentation is perceived as precise but overly academic. In this example, the user needs to F1: LOOP > LOOP AT itab - Basic Form > [cond] > WHERE logexp > and then without direct link on to > rel_exp - Comparison Expressions where he will find "operand [NOT] IN seltab. This is a 5 hop navigation that - although correct - is not intuitive.

Comment: @Florian: "The documentation is perceived as precise but overly academic." may be you can mention this to Horst Keller... :)

Comment: @Florian overly academic and not intuitive, that's a good abstract

Comment: @JozsefSziksai Horst probably knows that, it's probably very difficult and long to reorganize this huge amount of documentation - It would be interesting to propose him another solution, maybe it's why nobody tried yet :) (AFAIK)

Comment: One way to know if it works is trying, for me the question has implicitly the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is the same like by SELECTs:

```
LOOP AT ...
     INTO|ASSIGNING ...
     WHERE field IN range.
  ...
ENDLOOP.
```